# sqoop execute import can't print mapreduce information

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Today I installed `sqoop-1.4.6` in `hadoop` cluster, when I use sqoop import data to hdfs and it's ok, but when I see the sqoop log, it's only a little log and not print `mapreduce` to the log file.  I think the reason from hadoop but I don't know how to resolve it.

The `sqoop` log info shows:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/hbase/hbase-1.1.5/lib/phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/hbase/hbase-1.1.5/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] Note:
>   /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/737c3aeaaf2b0b38c618b5a7bd2b3411/QueryResult.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Try adding `--verbose` with your command.

Comment: I had add --verbose args but it's not what I want to see. I need see the effect record from log.